# How to return a reference of std::vector in the function?

Tags: c++

I assume that the reference of the vector is not working correctly in C++.

For example, I pass the reference of v to change() and get the return as a reference of v, the returned v is not the same as the input of change().  This does not make sense to me because I assume that we can use & for the call by reference and return it as a reference to out of the function.

I used the pointer to see if the addresses of the input v and output v are the same. But change() makes a new copy of v and returns it although I use & to return it as a reference.

---

If I run the following code, v1 and v2 are not the same.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;
    using std::vector;
    
    const vector<int>& const change(vector<int>& v) {
      v[1] = -1;             // change the elements in v
      return v;              // return a vector as reference
    }
    
    int main() {

      vector<int> v1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
      vector<int> v2 = change(v1);
    
      cout << &v1.at(0) << endl;  // check the address of v1
      cout << &v2.at(0) << endl;  // check the address of v2
    
      for (int e : v1) {
        cout << e << ",";
      }
      cout << endl;
    
      for (int e : v2) {
        cout << e << ",";
      }
      cout << endl;
      v1[4] = 10;
      v2[4] = 20;
    
      for (int e : v1) {
      cout << e << ",";
      }
      cout << endl;
      for (int e : v2) {
          cout << e << ",";
      }
        cout << endl;
    }
```

Resulting output:

```
    [result]
    000002568AA719E0
    000002568AA71B70
    1,-1,3,4,5,
    1,-1,3,4,5,
    1,-1,3,4,10,
    1,-1,3,4,20,
```

The addresses of v1 and v2 are not the same. That means, const vector& const change(vector& v) returns a copy of v.

I use the following code, but v1 and v2 are not the same. The outcome does not make a sense to me. Is there any way to return the reference of vector without copying the data in C++?

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;
    using std::vector;
    
    const vector<int> * const change(vector<int>& v) {
        v[1] = -1;                // change the elements in v
        return &v;                // return a pointer
    }
    
    int main() {

        vector<int> v1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        vector<int> v2 = * (change(v1));
    
        cout << &v1.at(0) << endl;   // check the address of v1
        cout << &v2.at(0) << endl;   // check the address of v2
    
        for (int e : v1) {           // print v1
          cout << e << ",";
        }
        cout << endl;
    
        for (int e : v2) {           // print v2
          cout << e << ",";
        }
        cout << endl;
        v1[4] = 10;
        v2[4] = 20;
    
        for (int e : v1) {           // print v1
          cout << e << ",";
        }
        cout << endl;
        for (int e : v2) {           // print v2 
          cout << e << ",";
        } 
        cout << endl;
    }
```

Resulting Output:

```
    [result]
    000001CD273129C0
    000001CD27312600
    -1,3,4,5,
    1,-1,3,4,5,
    1,-1,3,4,10,
    1,-1,3,4,20,
```

The outcome does not make a sense to me.

Is there any way to return the reference of vector without copying the data in C++?

Comment: Your function is returning a reference. The variable you are initializing from the result of the function call is not a reference variable.

Comment: Why do you expect them to be the same? This is expecting objects in C++ to work like they do in Java and C#. C++ is not Java or C#, and C++ objects work in fundamentally different ways.

Comment: Do you understand that returning anything from `change()` is excessive? You can do it to make it more convenient to use in some cases, but it doesn't have any actual effect, as `bar = change(foo)` is equivalent to `change(foo); bar = foo;` since you pass by reference.

Comment: @SamVarshavvchik stricly speaking also in Java two distinct object don't have the same adress. You just dont get your hands on the objects but only references

Comment: Why are you returning anything?

Comment: I don't understand.  If your are passing a parameter by reference, you should be modifying that variable and not returning a reference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`v1` and `v2` are two distinct objects. Here:

> ```
> vector<int> v2 = change(v1);
> ```

you use the reference to `v1` returned from the function to initialize a second vector called `v2`.

If you want to store the reference returned from the function (rather than initializing a new vector), then you need a reference:

```
const vector<int>& v2 = change(v1);
     //    ^---------------------- !!!
```

Note that it must be a `const` reference because the reference returned from the function is `const`.

---

Consider this much simpler example with the same effect:

```
#include <iostream>

int& foo(int& x) { return x;}

int main() {
  int a = 42;
  int b = foo(a);
  std::cout << &a << " " << &b;
}
```

[Possible output](https://godbolt.org/z/sMx4oMvWx):

```
0x7ffc99a389ac 0x7ffc99a389a8
```

The two addresses cannot possibly be the same, because `a` and `b` are two different objects. On the other hand, taking the address of a reference yields the address of the referenced object, hence this will print two times the same address:

```
  int a = 42;
  int& b = foo(a);
  std::cout << &a << " " << &b;
```

---

> Is there any way to return the reference of vector without copying the data in C++?

Yes. Your function does return a reference to the vector. The copy in your code happens when you invoke the copy constructor for `v2`. Though, your function is already modifying `v1` so there is no need to return the reference.

Comment: vector<int>& v2 = change(v1);     // compile error

Comment: @ignudiks yes sorry, I overlooked that you are returning a constant reference. See edit. And note that there is no point in returning the reference. The caller already passed a reference to the function, so they dont need it again returned

Comment: *I may see the source code inside the vector or assembly code to see what happens here.* -- Why do you need to do that?  The rules are quite clear -- if you return a const reference, and you want to assign it to a reference, the reference must be `const`.

Comment: Now I see the issue here. I assign a constant as a return. After removing it, I can receive the reference. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @ignudiks -- In general, you won't learn C++ properly or at the very least, get stopped dead in your tracks of learning C++ by trying to look at the source code to figure out how C++ works.  If you want to learn how to fly a plane, you don't examine the plane engine.

Comment: @ignudiks btw this isnt a comment. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you for your advice. Just I want to double-check if C++ works correctly according to the specifications.